# _Pairib': is not a member of 'std::map,std::allocator>>

Tags: c++

I recently updated my Visual Studio and now I am getting lots of errors that relate back to `_Pairib`. Does anyone know what's going on and how I can fix this?

**Error**:

```
C2039    '_Pairib': is not a member of 'std::map<int,std::string,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const
_Kty,_Ty>>>'
        with
        [
            _Kty=int,
            _Ty=std::string
        ]
Sample  C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Sample\Sample\Sample.cpp    12
```

**Sample Code**

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> test_map;

    std::map<int, std::string>::_Pairib res = test_map.insert(std::map<int, std::string>::value_type(0, "Test"));
    if (!res.second)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Pairib`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_Pairib` is an internal implementation detail and should never have been used in your code.  The easiest fix is to replace all those with `auto`:

```
auto res = test_map.insert(std::map<int, std::string>::value_type(0, "Test"));
```

But if you need to specify the type it is a `std::pair` with the first element an iterator and the second a bool.  (`std::pair<iterator,bool>` where `iterator` is `std::map<int, std::string>::iterator`.)

Comment: Specifically was removed in 14.2227905: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/666356/pairib-removed-in-msvc-142227905include.html

Comment: @Chuu officially it never has been there ;) Implementation details are best left alone